# What SQL Server syntax is this where the NULL is behind the column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2012

In a `SELECT` statement like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT NULL[Column1], NULL[Column2], Column2, etc...
FROM Table
```

What exactly are the NULL statements doing before the column names? This runs fine.

Comment: those column names become aliases for the value `null`. Should be `null as [column1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NULL` is the value.  The column name is the name of the column.

I would write this as:

```
select distinct null as column1, . . ..
```

The `as` makes it more clear that name is being given the value.

In SQL Server, you can also use:

```
select distinct column1 = null, . . .
```

I don't like this shorthand (because it is not supported by other databases and it looks too much like variable assignment).  However, it is popular among some people.

Comment: I'm a some people! [.... column aliases - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: I too am a some people. I find it a lot easier to maintain queries when the name of the column being output is right at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @SqlZim Read the comments though...What does one do when Bertrand and Celko disagree????? It's enough to make your head spin. Regardless, I'm of the opinion that whoever wrote `NULL[Column1]` should be forever banned from touching a keyboard.

Comment: @Shawn `select top 1 * from (values ('Aaron Bertrand'),('Joe Celko')) v (name) order by name` -- though if I worked with sql on as many platforms as Gordon Linoff does, I would eschew non-ANSI syntax as much as possible.

Comment: @SqlZim I run that and it keeps returning `42`. :-)

Comment: @Shawn As it should!